# Word text style with NO indentation only at the first paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Is there a way to create a Office Word *text style* that does **not indent the first line**, but that does **indent all the following paragraphs**?

Sample:

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaa.
  Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
```

Comment: https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=indent%20first%20line%20of%20paragraph%20word&safe=off

Comment: @Hannu, I know how to indent the first line only... Your google search did not help. Also, I know how to google. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Well, then you know how to activate it ;-) -- now you need to put it in a template document (.dot, .dotx) or a style. I believe you got answer with that now.  That is: Add new style, edit it and find the  button in the lower left of the dialog.

Comment: Is it possible to post a sample image please?

Comment: @Prasanna, I don't think Hannu understands your scenario properly so his suggestion is of no help to you. I think I have a solution for you, see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes this is possible:

1. Create a new style. This will be the actual style that you will
   apply in the document. Apply the formatting you want but don't set
   any first line indent.
2. Create another style, this will be a secondary style and not
   directly set by you so you may wish to hide it so it doesn't appear
   in the quick style pane. Set this style to be based on the first
   style you created so formatting in inherited and add a First line
   indent to the paragraph formatting.
3. Under options for the newly created style set **Style for Following
   paragraph** to point to itself (so subsequent paragraphs have this style applied)
4. In options for the first style you created Set **Style for Following
   paragraph** to the second style.

[image]

Once this is set up you can set the first style to a paragraph and after pressing enter a few times you will see all paragraphs have first line indent except for the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, actually I was already using it. The problem is that you need to be careful with the paragraphs formatting, eg: if you remove a paragraph, if you add unformatted text you can't just click "Body text", you will need to unhide the formatting or joining the text with the previous paragraph and hit enter, so it "gets" the correct formatting.

Comment: @Pedro77, Yes you're right, however I think it's easy to see any paragraphs that aren't styled correctly and a backspace and enter on any offending paragraph to correct it isn't too bad right :)? I think this is as good as it gets for Word